# express log-log relationship as an exponential relationship

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

I have several log(y) ~ a + b * log(x) models that I want to express as exponential relationships. I know this involves an expoential transformation, but how do I solve it?

Example:

Step 1: log(y) ~ 2 + 3 * log(x)

Step 2: exp(log(y)) ~ exp(2 + 3 * log(x))

Step 3: exp(log(y)) ~ exp(2) + exp(3 * log(x))

what comes next for the exp(3 * log(x)) part?

I'm using a natural logarithm.

Comment: $3^{3\log x} = (e^{\log x})^3 = x^3$.  You have $\log y = 2+3\log x$ so $e^{\ln y} = e^{2+3\ln x}$ so $y = e^2e^{3\ln x} = e^2x^3$.

Comment: thanks @fleablood, but I don't think I understand how the exp(3 * ln x) becomes x^3.

Comment: $e^{\log a}=a ,$ for all a. if you sub $a=x^3$.... can you see it?

Comment: @AntonyTheo thanks, that helps!

Comment: $a^{bc} = (a^b)^c$ and $e^{\log w} = w$.  So $e^{k\log w} = (e^{\log w})^k = (w)^k = w^k$.  ... or do you not see how $e^{\log w} = w$?.  Consider the very *definition* of $\log w= k$ is $e^k = w$.  Thus if $\log w = k$ then $e^{\log w} = e^k$ and that $k$ is the *very* $k$ that makes $e^k = w$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some  logarithm properties to have in mind

- $\log(ab)=\log a+\log b$
- $\log({a\over b})=\log a -\log b$
- $\log a^b = b \log a $
- $loge^a=a$

(NOTE: when i write $\log $ I am referring to the natural logarithm a.k.a $\ln , \log_e$
also $e^a=\exp(a)$)

back to your example

You were almost there !

$\log(y)=2+3\log(x) \implies e^{\log(y)}=e^{2+3\log(x)} \implies y=e^2 \cdot e^{3\log(x)} \implies y=e^2 \cdot e^{\log(x^3)} \implies y=e^2 \cdot x^3$

(also note that $e^{a+b}
= e^a \cdot e^b $)

EDIT

after a bit of playing around with equations of the form $\log(y)=a+b \cdot \log(c) $ we can see the following

$\log(y)=a+b \cdot \log(c) \implies \log(y)=\log e^a + \log(c^b) \implies \log(y)=\log(e^a \cdot c^b) $

$\implies e^{\log(y)}=e^{\log(e^a \cdot c^b)} \implies y= e^a \cdot c^b$

and that is the general simplified form of those types of expressions in terms of $y$. Although I would not recommend just taking this and substituting in you $a,b,c$ values especially if you are still not really comfortable with those types of problems